# Faster ways of slicing a big data set

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to slice a large data set in accordance to some specific length. I have made a code but it takes a lot of execution time.

First, i have data frame which consists of values that the large data set to be sliced.

```
df
sl no    length_of each_column
1           3
2           20
3           30
4           40
5           50
```

The large data set contains about hundred thousand of rows and somewhat looks like this

```
sl no      values
0           10
1           20
3           30
4           40
5           50
6           60
7           10
8           49
9           59
10          20
and so on
```

My resultant data set should slice the large data set by taking values from the data frame which contains length of each column. If suppose length of each column is 3, then it should slice the large data set by 3, then move forward by one row, then again slice 3 data points

Again move forward by one row and slice 3 data points and so on till it takes all possible combinations of required length.

The resultant data set is mentioned below

Resultant data set if sliced by 3

```
Resultant data frame for column length 3
sl no    col1     col2   col3  - - - - - - - 
0          10      20     30
1          20      30     40
2          30      40     50
```

and so on till it makes all possible combinations of length 3.

Comment: Would you mind reformatting the display of your dataframe data?

Comment: @Kundan can you post head of you data frame and desired output?

Comment: @Kundan ok, you need slice the data with a constant step or create all possible combinations like [10,20,30], [10,40,50], [10,20,50] ...?

Comment: with a constant step...if it's 3 then make all possible combinations of column length 3...if it's 10, the makes all possible combinations of column length 10 from the larger data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas as pd

# setup test data
slice_options = {'length_of each_column': ['3', '5']}
slice_options = pd.DataFrame(data=slice_options)

data = {'values': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=data)


# store data frames in list
out_data = list(range(slice_options.shape[0]))

count = 0
for index, row in slice_options.iterrows():
    # create empty data frame
    out_data[count] = pd.DataFrame()
    # collect data
    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        # select data rows
        select_data = data.iloc[i:i+int(row.values[0])]
        # handle rows number
        if select_data.shape[0] == int(row.values[0]):
            # fill data frame
            out_data[count]['column' + str(i)] = select_data.values.ravel()
    count += 1
```

Output:

```
df1 (3 elements):

  column0 column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6
0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8
2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9

df2 (5 elements):

  column0 column1 column2 column3 column4
0       1       2       3       4       5
1       2       3       4       5       6
2       3       4       5       6       7
3       4       5       6       7       8
4       5       6       7       8       9
```

Comment: It's working fine....but are there any faster way of doing this.....i have around millions of rows....and while slicing the data with a larger number takes a lot of execution time...

Comment: @Kundan this solution using pandas data frame is pretty fast, at the moment i don't try to find faster solution